# Plot checkboxes questions: combine multiple catplots on the same graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some data coming from a "checkboxes question" that I would like to plot.
By "checkboxes question", I mean that multiple of the proposed options could be checked.
The system I used works with that kind of question by creating one column per proposed option. It then puts a "Y" in a cell of that column if the answer was checked by the corresponding respondent.
The dataframe therefore looks as follows:

| Age | Option1 | Option2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Y | Y |
| 99 |  | Y |
| 28 | Y |  |
| 32 |  |  |

Seaborn easily lets me "catplot" each option separately.
Example code with a bee swarm plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [12, 99, 28, 32], 'Option1': ['Y', np.NaN, 'Y', np.NaN], 'Option2': ['Y', 'Y', np.NaN, np.NaN]})
sns.catplot(x="Option1", y="Age", kind="swarm", data=df)
plt.show()
```

This would give me the following result once all plots are combined (probably using subfigures): [image: Possible result with current solution:]

What I would like to do is to combine the catplots for all options into one figure but I would like to avoid grid-based subplots and instead combine the plots directly onto the same graph "area", with one x axis tick per option.
The desired result would be as follows:

[image]

How would I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to reshape your data first:

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
...
df = df.melt(id_vars='Age', var_name='Option').dropna()

color = sns.color_palette()[0]
sns.catplot(x='Option', y='Age', kind='swarm', data=df, color=color)
```

Output:

[image]